# box-shadow over floating divs

Tags: html, css-float, css

I got a problem rendering box-shadows over floating divs!
Ive tested in chrome and firefox with the same result.

```
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div style="float:left; clear: left; background-color: #aaa; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 8px #000; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
            </div>
            <div style="float:left; clear: left; background-color: #aaa; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 8px #000; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Edit: The div on top doesn't render its shadow on the div below, is there any fix for this problem or do I have to try a different solution?

regards 
/Joel

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Works for me in Firefox 4, but that code will never work on chrome or safari, the `-moz` is a vendor tag indicating mozilla.

You need add all of the following

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 8px #000; width: 200px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 8px #000; width: 200px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 8px #000; width: 200px;
```

`-webkit` is the vendor tag for Chrome/Safari, the following will add in drop shadows for the vendors that support it and then when it's universally supported the last rule will cover all browsers.

Edit: To get the top div's dropshadow over the other element you must `position:relative` and then give it a `z-index` higher than the bottom one.

Comment: You really se 2 divs with shadows? The div on top should cast shadow on the div below. All i see is one big box with shadow.

Comment: Sorry your question is a little ambiguous. You need to relatively position your element and then use z-index to get the top one over the other. See: http://jsfiddle.net/YjPRN/

Comment: Awsome :D Ill fix the question.

Comment: `position: relative` is important and fixed my problem!

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with them? If you're worried about not seeing the bottom shadow of the top `div` it's because you need a little separation. If you're having trouble seeing the box-shadow it's because you need to use vendor-specific prefixes at this stage, like so.

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/q5yf3](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/q5yf3/)**

If you want them to be stuck together, just give the first `div` a `z-index` with `position:relative` and it will look how you want it to.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bs up"></div>
<div class="bs"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.bs {
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    margin:1em;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#aaa;
    box-shadow:0 8px 8px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 8px 8px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 8px 8px #000;
}
div.up { z-index:10; position:relative; }
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/VaVhy](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/VaVhy/)**

That said, I'd also recommend looking into using [`rgba()`](http://24ways.org/2009/working-with-rgba-colour) instead of hex values for `box-shadow` color as it renders the shadow a lot more naturally on non flat-colored backgrounds.

Comment: Yeah I dont have any margin between my divs, and i need to keep them stuck togheter or at least make them appear so. As soon as i add background-color the shadow disappears.

Comment: Ah right, I've added a second part to my answer which relates to your problem, after the first link to a demo.

Comment: Ill keep the rgba() tip in mind when i try this out.
Thank u very much.

Answer (score 1):

looks fine in firefox because you are using `-moz-box-shadow`, for webkit browsers you will have to use `-webkit-box-shadow`

Comment: Yeah I know about that, i just kept the code small. i doesnt work for me in 3.6. do you see 2 boxes with shadow or one?

Comment: both have shadow on the right, the lower one has a shadow at the bottom, if you want both to have a bottom shadown then just separate the div's slightly use a '<br />' for quickness, or change the margins of the divs