# Box-shadow, float:left and overflow:auto don't like eachother's situation

Tags: css

My box-shadow stops if I use a parent div with overflow:auto. How do I fix this?
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992590/box-shadow-over-floating-divs) I found that I need to use position:relative and z-index, but that doesn't seem to work.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />Tri-tip fatback sausage speck, pork chop pastrami flank sirloin filet mignon t-bone rump ribeye chicken venison. Shankle ground round pancetta pastrami, sirloin beef ribs pork chop short loin. Salami pork boudin, ham hock flank tri-tip drumstick turkey shank short loin beef ribs kielbasa tail pastrami. Kielbasa beef ribs chicken, turkey drumstick bresaola sirloin ball tip chuck pig andouille. Cow sirloin shoulder beef ribs strip steak tongue jerky. Spare ribs capicola swine fatback, corned beef jerky kielbasa frankfurter pancetta flank sirloin short loin.</li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />Strip steak speck tri-tip drumstick pork chop spare ribs.</li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" /></li>
</ul>​
```

css:

```
ul{margin:10px;position:relative;z-index:18;}
li{overflow:auto;margin-bottom:10px;position:relative;z-index:19;}
li:hover{background:lightblue;}
li img{float:left; box-shadow:0 0 10px black; margin: 0 10px 10px 0;display:block;position:relative;z-index:20;}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/suNUK/1/

Comment: For me, on Chrome, box-shadows are just fine in your demo. (Puyol rocks btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can **clearfix** method for this. Write like this:

```
li{margin-bottom:10px;position:relative;z-index:19;}
li:after{
    content:'';
    clear:both;
    display:block;
}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/suNUK/2/